# What does this ASM line mean?

Tags: security, assembly, x86

Alright so I have this line in my assembly

```
004D0126 | 8981 BC0A8100 | MOV     DWORD PTR [ECX+810ABC], EAX |
```

what does this code do?

Answer (score 3):

It means: store the 32 bit value in register EAX at address ECX+810ABC.

Comment: what is ECX? and what is a Register? the value in the process at 00810ABC Is dynamic and has 3 different values.

Comment: @Joe: ECX is a register - it probably contains the base address of some chunk of data.

Comment: how do i store the value in ECX+810ABC just a bit longer then the game allows. 00810ABC is inside the EXE file. it has three different values depending on what is happening during game play. so how would i extend the time that ECX+810ABC stays at value 7 before returning too value 3 during game play without having to use hot keys. i would rather code inject. its function is cyclic in the game.  i just want to extend the cycle a bit longer then the game does

Comment: @Joe: you would need to do a *lot* more analysis of all the code in order to better understand how it works, and then come up with a suitable patch.

Comment: ok. is there anyone who could analyze this code for me? only because i dont understated asm code at all.

Comment: TANSTAAFL applies - if you want to hack code like a pro then you'll need to invest some time and effort into gaining the relevant skills.